# Need to access properties of extended ToggleButton class through OnCheckChangedListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-togglebutton

I am trying to extend the `ToggleButton` class in a new class called `TagToggleButton`, whose sole difference is the fact that it has an ID that I can set associated with it. The `TagToggleButton` class looks as follows:

```
public class TagToggleButton extends ToggleButton {

    private long tagId;

    public TagToggleButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TagToggleButton(Context context, long id) {
        super(context);
        this.setTagId(id);
    }

    public void setTagId(long id) {
        this.tagId = id;
    }

    public long getTagId() {
        return this.tagId;
    }

}
```

I then want to call an OnClickListener that will allow me to get the ID property of the button. For instance:

```
tag.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new TagToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            long id = buttonView.getTagId();
            // will do something with id afterwards
        } else {
            //Will do something else if the button isn't checked
        }
    }
```

However, I cannot call `getTagId` on `buttonView` as it is defined as a `CompoundButton`. How can I change `buttonView` to the type of `TagToggleButton` (that is, how do I override the `OnCheckedChangeListener` class within my `TagToggleButton` method?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried casting the `CompoundButton` `buttonView` to `TagToggleButton` inside the `onCheckedChanged` method?

Comment: @rere252 No I have not, didn't realize that was valid. I can do this directly within the onCheckedChanged method I described? (as in I don't need to further edit the TagToggleButton class?)

Comment: I tried the following: `long id = (TagToggleButton) buttonView.getTagId();` and it still comes up as an unresolved method in Android studio

Comment: Try `((TagToggleButton) buttonView).getTagId();`.

Comment: That works! Thanks! @rere252 would you be able to submit an answer and then I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `onCheckedChanged` method cast the `CompoundButton` `buttonView` to `TagToggleButton`. To get the tag id you could do something like `long id = ((TagToggleButton) buttonView).getTagId();`